# Tumblr hosted video fluid width and height

Tags: html, css, video

I wanted to make a Tumblr theme with various post widths to choose from, setting video posts up has been quite difficult because of this.

This code:

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,  
.video-container object,  
.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and

```
{block:Video}
<div class="video-container">
{Video-500}
</div>
{block:Caption}
{Caption}
{/block:Caption}
{/block:Video}
```

works flawlessly with YouTube videos, but it trims down Tumblr hosted videos.
Latest default Tumblr theme [Optica](http://www.tumblr.com/theme/37310) has something that makes this work, meaning Tumblr hosted videos stay of their original height, but I don't know what... Could anyone help with this? Not necessarily the same way this works in Optica theme, just... Any way?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Tumblr doesn't seem to follow a specific aspect ratio for its videos, unlike Youtube.

`padding-bottom: 56.25%` gives you an aspect ratio of 16:9 (http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-youtube-videos/).

Each Tumblr video may have a different aspect ratio, so each one will need a different `padding-bottom` value.

Simplest solution would be to use **fitVids.js**:

jQuery version: http://fitvidsjs.com/

Javascript version: https://github.com/rosszurowski/vanilla-fitvids

You can roll your own, the source of either version explains pretty well what is needed to make the calculation.

**Enable Tumblr Videos with Fitvids.js**

The `src` is a little different for videos host by Tumblr. They do some javascript magic.

```
$(".videos").fitVids({ customSelector: "iframe[src='about:blank']"});
```

Comment: I know that, actually, and I tried fitVids but it didn't work because I couldn't find a way to make it apply to Tumblr hosted videos, too.
I tried adding this to the script:
`"iframe[src*='tumblr.com']",`
and this too:
`$("#videos").fitVids({ customSelector: "iframe[src*='tumblr.com']"});`

Comment: Urm ok, I was only trying to help. I have updated the answer with the Custom Selector.

Comment: I'm sorry if I came off as offensive and unappreciative of your help, I didn't mean to, this has been bugging me for a few days and I'm frustrated. Anyways I tried `$(".videos").fitVids({ customSelector: "iframe[src*='about:blank']"});` but it actually just makes Tumblr hosted videos not show at all..